# Reversing machine learning models to get particular features

Tags: machine-learning, gradient, random-forest, boosting

I am trying to model a process. My input data includes certain features and measurements about the product. I built Random forests and Gradient boosting models in Python, and got good results. I am now trying to determine which features and measurements lead to the best product (almost like reversing an equation to get the x variable back for a particular y). How can I go about doing this?

Comment: If you are using random forest you can check the attributes importance. It is basically the attribute used in most of the trees at the top level split.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically doing the feature selection so here are some examples you could try out

[Feature selection](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning-with-python-f24e7da3f36e)

I was using some of the below for my feature selection which ranks your features based on the spread of the data

1. [Fishers score](https://github.com/pidugusundeep/scikit-feature/blob/master/skfeature/function/similarity_based/fisher_score.py)
2. [F score](https://github.com/pidugusundeep/scikit-feature/blob/master/skfeature/example/test_f_score.py)
3. [chi Squ](https://github.com/pidugusundeep/scikit-feature/blob/master/skfeature/example/test_chi_square.py)

I found the above usefull.